# split image with very long height in two pages in python reportlab story

Tags: python, reportlab

I have figure from matplotlib with very long height, I want to append the image in report lab story but it givers error (reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Flowable <Image at 0x227af5d5908 frame=normal filename=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000227AF74E2E8>>(432.0 x 3024) too large on page 12 in frame 'normal'(456.0 x 636.0*) of template 'LaterP')

I want to split the image in two pages if the image height greater than page size

````
def get_image(path, width=1 * inch):
    "function to read image bytes and insert it in reportlab"
    img = utils.ImageReader(path)
    iw, ih = img.getSize()
    aspect = ih / float(iw)
    return Image(path, width=width, height=ih)
image_data = BytesIO()            
   log_plot.savefig(
            image_data, format="jpg", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.1, dpi=150,edgecolor=log_plot.get_edgecolor())
 image=get_image(image_data,6*inch)
story.append(image)```
````